# How can I make my MKMapView annotations show up?

Tags: objective-c, ios, annotations, mkmapview

I'm new to this, and I'm banging my head on a wall, so any help you can provide would be appreciated.

My app is downloading a series of coordinates and titles which I'm turning into MKAnnotations.  I've implemented the MKAnnotation protocol well enough because it's stopped complaining about that, but here's the code:

Annotator.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MapKit/Mapkit.h"

@interface Annotator : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

+ (Annotator *) createAnnotator:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coordinate
                      withTitle:(NSString *)title
                    andSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *myTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mySubtitle;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D *coordinate;

@end
```

Pretty boring so far.  Here's Annotator.m:

```
#import "Annotator.h"

@implementation Annotator

@synthesize myTitle = _myTitle;
@synthesize mySubtitle = _mySubtitle;
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;

+ (Annotator *)createAnnotator:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)coordinate
                     withTitle:(NSString *)title
                   andSubtitle:(NSString *)subtitle
{
    Annotator *annotation = [[Annotator alloc] init];
    annotation.myTitle = title;
    annotation.mySubtitle = subtitle;
    annotation.coordinate = coordinate;
    return annotation;
}

- (NSString *)title
{
    return self.myTitle;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle
{
    return self.mySubtitle;
}

@end
```

Right now, I've got most of the other code in a central view controller, so as soon as the HTTP request returns with the data, I iterate through it, creating my MKAnnotation objects, and then do this for each one:

```
[self.territoryMap addAnnotation:locationPin];
```

...where self.territoryMap is an outlet to the MKMapView I dragged into my storyboard, and locationPin is the MKAnnotation object I created with my Annotator implementation above.

Some of the solutions I've looked at have MKMapViewDelegate methods in place, but it seems to me that they shouldn't be necessary, as I'm just looking for the default behavior.  I put in one delegate that I found which allowed me to change the color of the user's location pin, but that's not what I'm worried about.

Is there something else I need to be doing?  I'm confused!  Thanks for whatever help you can provide!

Comment: Right before the addAnnotation line, put `NSLog(@"coord=%f,%f; map=%@", locationPin.coordinate.latitude, locationPin.coordinate.longitude, self. territoryMap);`.  What does it log for the coordinates (are the lats/longs correct)?  What does it log for map (is it nil by any chance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the MapViews delegate. Then it should work fine.

Alternatively look into this: http://maybelost.com/2011/01/a-basic-mapview-and-annotation-tutorial/ 
It looks pretty much like that what you are trying to do!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I did a quick look at the tutorial and it didn't appear that the delegate was required there, so I'm still a little confused, but I still appreciate the link, since this one looks like a better parallel to what I'm looking for than other ones I've found.

I think what I'll do next is implement that example on its own to see if that works for me.  It may be that there's something else in my morass of code that's breaking things.  Wish me luck!

Comment: OK, it turns out I was wrong; my original protocol implementation apparently did not conform to <MKAnnotation>.  I thought it did because (a) the code stopped erroring out and (b) I could get the title and coordinates into the debug log just fine.  But changing my protocol (and the way I call it) to match this one (with some small adjustments) worked fine.

I'm still a little confused and need to figure out what I did wrong, but at least it's working.  Thanks for pointing me the right way!